# Magento How can i modify catalogs category controller to do custom sorting?

Tags: php, magento

As i'm new to magento development i don't understand everything that system does... Some of the features are realy nice and helpfull, but when i wanted to add custom sort.... well i stuck on that :(

I want to implement custom sorting so that i select manufacturer and then the manufacturer i select is first in the list and after that all other manufacturers.... In example when i select Nike in the dropdown products made by Nike will be first and then Badidas, Puma etc..

How would this be acomplished?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need to add any custom sorting method for your requirement.
In the back end you edit the manufacture attribute then you select "yes" for "Used for Sorting in Product Listing" option and save.

and then check.